# perl: build big/little endian bigfields and output them with a single pack

Tags: perl, bit-fields

I'm building binary data in perl. 
This binary data is based on a C structure, and is used on 32 and 64bit, big and little endian systems.
The diffucult part is the bitfield in the FORMAT structure. This is layed out differently in memory on little/big endian architectures.

I am currently making the bitfields like this:

```
struct FORMAT
{
 void * X,
 void * Y,
 void * Z,
 unsigned int size   : 26;
 unsigned int type   :  6;
 <4 byte padding on 64bit targets>
}

my $size = 0x3C;
my $type = 0x05;

=> big endian
print pack("L>", $size << 6) | pack("L>", $type);  # 00 00 0f 05
=> little endian
print pack("L<", $size) | pack("L<", $type << 26); # 3c 00 00 14
```

But I would like to have the above in a single pack format,(and thus not call pack two times, and OR the result and then print it.)

Eventually I want to print an entire FORMAT record in one shot.

```
 pack("Q>3L>L>", X, Y, Z, ???, 0) #64bit big endian
```

I have about 500k FORMAT records that I need to write out, and calling pack() multiple times for each record is too costly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use XS. This will handle endianness and compiler-specific alignment (padding) for you.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Inline C => <<'__EOC__';

   typedef struct {
      void* X;
      void* Y;
      void* Z;
      unsigned int size: 26;
      unsigned int type:  6;
   } FORMAT;

   SV* pack_FORMAT(UV X, UV Y, UV Z, unsigned int size, unsigned int type) {
      FORMAT format;
      format.X = INT2PTR(void*, X);
      format.Y = INT2PTR(void*, Y);
      format.Z = INT2PTR(void*, Z);
      format.size = size;
      format.type = type;
      return newSVpvn(&format, sizeof(format));
   }

__EOC__

my $size = 0x3C;
my $type = 0x05;

my $packed = pack_FORMAT(0, 0, 0, $size, $type);
printf("%v02X\n", $packed);
```

---

That said

```
pack("L>", $size << 6) | pack("L>", $type)
pack("L<", $size) | pack("L<", $type << 26)
```

can be written as

```
pack("L>", ($size << 6) | $type)
pack("L<", $size | ($type << 26))
```